# How to move HTML element with ember.js

Tags: css, ember.js

I would like to move an element with ember.js. What is the best practice?

"move" does not mean that I move an element on coordinates,XY.
It means that I change parent element for the element I want to move.
Additonaly,I want to add css3 animation to the element moving.

I would like to do as follows.

**before**

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="moved"></div>
</div>
<div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

**after**

```
<div id="foo">
</div>
<div id="bar">
  <div id="moved"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish though? Reason I ask is because if you are trying to manipulate the DOM to do something as basic as that, you are sort of fighting the framework. What you'd want to do instead is bind it to regions in a template and switch some kind of flag to display it in on region or another. But a clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

animation aside, and the fact that the entire approach may be wrong also aside, if your code is literally as simple as that, you can probably use jQuery to safely detach the element from it's old location and append it to its destination element.  if you use Chrome Developer Tools and do Inspect Element, and see ember-related markup that you don't know what it's doing in between your moving element's source and destination, you might mess something up by using jQuery.

```
var d = $("#moved").detach();
d.appendTo("#bar");
```

or just

```
$("#moved").appendTo("#bar");
```